# Conditional formula field

Tags: formula, conditional

If I have the object `Animal__c`with the fields`Color__c` and `Shape__c`. How Can I make a conditional formula field `Country__c` which is dependent of the values of`Color__c`. Example:

```
    If (Color__c ='Blue'){
        Country__c = 'Germany';
    }else if(Color__c ='Red'){
        Country__c = 'France';
    }else{
      Country__c = 'Italy';
    }
```

How Can I do that in the Lightning console??

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, the Lightning Console? What are you trying to use? A formula field? JavaScript? Apex? Something else?

Comment: A formula field as stated in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a nested if statement IF(Color__c = 'Blue', Country__c = 'Germany',
  IF(Color__c = 'Red', Country__c = 'France'....etc

But it looks like a case statement is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

if you just need a formula field then you can try this-

```
CASE( Color__c , 'Red', 'France', 'Blue', 'Germany','Italy')
```